# The document.body.innerHTML.replace() replaces the url in the address bar

Tags: firefox-addon

I am trying to make an extension as part of which i want certain words in the web pages to be highlighted. The document.body.innerHTML.replace() replaces the url in the address bar as well. So the moment this code gets exwecuted the page doesnt get loaded properly..
Is there a way around this problem?

```
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {  
       var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;
        var str="the";
 var regex;
 var regex = new RegExp(str, "g");
    doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML.replace(regex,'<b>'+str+'</b>');
}
```

The listener is registered as follows in a browser.xul overlay:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  myExtension.init();
}, false);
var myExtension = {
  init: function() {
    var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent"); // browser
    if(appcontent)
      appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, false);
  },
```

Comment: Where is the event handler attached to?

Comment: This might be relevant, not sure: "Current Firefox trunk nightlies will fire the onPageLoad function for not only documents, but xul:images (favicons in tabbrowser). If you only want to handle documents, ensure `aEvent.originalTarget.nodeName == "#document"`" from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load

Comment: window.addEventListener("load", function() { myExtension.init(); }, false);  
var myExtension = { 
 init: function() {   
var appcontent = document.getElementById("appcontent");   // browser  
       if(appcontent)  
         appcontent.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", myExtension.onPageLoad, false);  
             },

Comment: #MatrixFrog:Thanx a lot...That definitely works :)

Comment: could you post the answer yourself to help other people who come here looking for solutions? You might also get a badge for that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onPageLoad: function(aEvent) {       
  if(aEvent.originalTarget.nodeName=="#document"){
    var doc = aEvent.originalTarget;
    var str="the";  
    var regex;  
    var regex = new RegExp(str, "g");
    doc.body.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML.replace(regex,'<b>'+str+'</b>'); 
  } 
}
```

The if condition in the function happens to do the trick..
:)